# When and how do Death, Wolf and Crow meet?

Tags: story-identification, comics, east-of-west

I can't seem to remember whether it is shown in any issue of *East of West* how Death meet Endless Nation shamans Crow and Wolf, although some kind of deal they have with him is mentioned several times.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your question has attracted close votes because you have merged a few separate questions: when did they meet; what is the deal; who owes whom; and how come Death's colour changed.  You might want to [edit] your question to focus on a single, clear question.  You can post the other questions later.

Comment: @Piotr: you may even post all questions at the "same" time, but independently, using the "Ask question" button several times - once for each question.